# Why is the scanner not reading the text file and keeps on returning null?

Tags: java

The code is supposed to take a text file, and put it's contents (phrases) line by line into a phrase array. Then using a random index, select a random phrase from the phrase array. The problem is that the scanner does not read from the text file and returns "null".

```
  public static String phrasePicker()throws IOException{

                  Scanner input = new Scanner(new File ("Phrases.txt")); 
                  String [] phrases = new String [140];
                  int i = 0;
    //checks if there is a next line in the text file
                  while(input.hasNext()) {
    //if there is a text file, put that line as the index "i" of the array
                    phrases[i] = input.nextLine();
                    i= i++;
                  }
                  Random random = new Random();
                  int select = random.nextInt(phrases.length);
                  String phrase = phrases[select]; 
                  return phrase;
                }
```

Comment: `i=i++;` should be either `i++;` or `i=i+1;`

Comment: Just so you are aware, if your File has more lines than 140 you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Likewise, if you file is less than 140 lines, you may return a null value (which may not be what you want).

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
i= i++;
```

ends up not incrementing the value of `i`, so all the lines read from the file end up being written to `phrases[0]`, i.e. only the last line is stored at `phrases[0]`.  That line should be

```
i++;
```

or

```
i=i+1;
```

To explain, for `i=i++;` the following happens:

1. The current value of `i` (the initial value, `0`) is saved temporarily
2. `i` is incremented
3. The temporarily saved value of `i` is assigned back to `i`

Thus `i` never gets incremented.  This comes from the definition of the post-increment operator, i.e. the trailing `++`